# javascript onclick parent row corresponding child rows to show up

Tags: javascript

I have N parent rows,on click of each parent row the corresponding child rows

should display.

I am sending the parent id in onclick function but how to retieve

it in function and show?

```
<script language="javascript">
function add_rows(id)
{
//
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") 
                {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";

                return;
            }   

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr id="parent_1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button_small"  onclick="add_rows(parent_1);" value="Add newrow" align="left"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>

   <tr id="parent_2">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button_small"  onclick="add_rows(parent_2);" value="Add newrow" align="left"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Im guessing you have syntax errors? You're missing quotes around the id string parameter

Comment: I cleard the syntax errors, but how to show the corresponding child for each parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing similar stuff, so I worked on this. (I suggest you use "console.log"s to see what's going on.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_rows(id) {
  console.log("#1");
  var elt1 = document.getElementById(id); // one table
  console.log("elt1: ", elt1);
  elts1 = elt1.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  console.log("elts1: ", elts1, elts1.length);
  for (i=0; i<elts1.length; i++) {
    console.log("iiii: ", elts1[i].style.display  ); 
    if (elts1[i].style.display == "none") {
      elts1[i].style.display = "table-row"; 
      break; } }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodydiv">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="tableid1">
  <tr style="display:table-row">
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button_small" onclick="add_rows('tableid1');" value="Add newrow" align="left" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="1_row_4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="tableid2">
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button_small" onclick="add_rows('tableid2');" value="Add newrow" align="left"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" id="2_row_4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div><!-- bodyid -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **FIDDLE**:  http://jsfiddle.net/Anee/f6BS7/1/

Single quote the `id`

```
 <td><input type="button" class="button_small"  onclick="add_rows('parent_1');" value="Add newrow" align="left"/></td>


 <td><input type="button" class="button_small"  onclick="add_rows('parent_2');" value="Add newrow" align="left"/></td>
```

Also, in the js function, you have given id's accordingly...Make use of them to check if they are child elements.

**JS**

```
function add_rows(id)
{
   var newid = id.split("_");
   //console.log(newid);
   id = newid[1] + "_row_" + newid[1];
   for(var i = 1; i<= 4; i++){
        id = newid[1] + "_row_" + i;
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") 
            {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
        }   
    }

}
```